# PL SQL detailed Exception catch

Tags: plsql

I have a procedure which does a lot of inserts. I am getting a constraint violation, but it is not telling me which insert is causing it. I tried the exception catch below but it is not giving me enough detail.

```
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
  ROLLBACK;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Procedure failed with:  ' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error in '|| $$plsql_unit || ' at ' || $$plsql_line);
```

Comment: what kind of inserts? What about `FOR ALL ... SAVE EXCEPTIONS`?

Comment: Check [`dbms_utility`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_util.htm#ARPLS73195). See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16183290/. The question is not exact duplicate but the answer is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that I have always done this is to wrap each insert in a begin exception block.

so you would end up with

```
Begin
  insert statement here
exception when others then
  dbms_output statements
end;

Begin
  insert statement
exception when others
  dbms_output statements
end.
```

ect

This allows you to add customized output to each insert so you are 100% sure which insert is causing the issue.  It takes a bit of work to add but is worth it in the end as it saves you a lot of time in debugging.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: You're potentially doing it suboptimal way (YMMV thought). See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16187783/272735. In general separate exception blocks are not needed for reporting but only when different actions are required to resolve the exceptions.